# The AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager failed with error code 0xC001A004

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2014, snapshot, isolation-level

I use SQL Server 2014 and SSIS with Visual studio 2013.
I need to make some changes in one OLTP database (Here it is my destination database) in several tables with one of my SSIS package, and some times that takes a lot of time to execute and during this time it locks some tables in OLTP database and I can't anymore work with may application which works with OLTP database.

Before my package have been run one time in day and it was at midnight but now we decided to run this package every 30 min.

I need to use snapshot isolation level in OLTP databse to be sure that SSIS package does not lock the table for long time.

At first I want use IsolationLevel equal to Snapshot but it does not work.
[image]

Then I found that I should handel the Isolation leve manually inside the ControlFlow for using the Isolation Snapshot.

I have created a sample because my real SSIS package is really huge.

I have created a database and then, I have set Allow snapshot isolation with true.

[image]

After that I have created a SSIS package in which I have these variables:

[image]

Then I have created a Control flow like that :

[image]

In the first SQL Execution Task I have run this command:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SNAPSHOT
```

Then in second SQL Execution Task I have started a Transaction :

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
```

Then I have added a Dataflow task. Inside of my DataFlow task there are two OLE DB. One as source and second one is destination.

[image]

The source and target are both in the same server and in the different database.

Then I change the property of my Connection Manager like below :

[image]

And then I have installed and configured my MSDTC in my computer. (Source and Destination are both on the same server and ssis package is running in the same server).

[image]

Then I configur my service like that :

[image]

Then in my firewall I have given the access to MSDTC like that :

[image]

Then I have configured my firewall's advance configuration like that :

[image]

[image]

All of the Task in my SSIS package have these configurations for IsolationLevel and TransactionOption :

[image]

My control flow has these configurations :

[image]

When I run the package I get this error in my OLE DB destination.

[image]

```
[OLE DB Destination [2]] Error: SSIS Error Code
DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER.  
The AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager 
".<ServerName>.<DatabaseName>" failed with error code 0xC001A004.  
There may be error messages posted before 
this with more information on why the AcquireConnection method call failed.

[SSIS.Pipeline] Error: 
OLE DB Destination failed validation and returned error code 0xC020801C.
```

What should I do to be able to handel manually the transaction and isolation level as Snapshot in my SSIS package?